# Wrong response code happen when I request the URL using jsoup library

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am developing a WI-Fi application to connect the Hotspot network. While connecting I want to get the response code based on the state of the network. Suppose, if my SSID name is like "MyHotspot" I connect it in my mobile and check the state it comes in the state called "Authentication/sign In Required" In that state I am trying to request the URL using the jsoup parser. then I got the response code 302. This is the correct response code, but if my SSID is in "connected" state. that time also it shows the response code 302. It's wrong.

I want to receive the response code based on the SSID state. if SSID is in auth state, response will come 302.if SSID is in connect state, response will come 200. this is what i want.

**Source code :**

```
try{
    URL url = new URL("http://microsenseindia.com");
    Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(String.valueOf(url)).timeout(10000).followRedirects(false).execute();
    //Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("http://microsenseindia.com").timeout(10000).execute();
    Log.d(TAG, "check_if_internet_available : " + response.statusCode());
} catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Jsoup_Exception: "+e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all the code http 302

> [6.4.3. 302 Found](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.3)
>
> The 302 (Found) status code indicates that the target resource resides
> temporarily under a different URI. Since the redirection might be
> altered on occasion, the client ought to continue to use the effective
> request URI for future requests.

for your question maybe this code can help you without using the URL definition:

```
    try{
        JsoupConnection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("http://microsenseindia.com")
                      .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like 
                                      Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.46 Safari/536.5")
                      .timeout(100000)
                      .ignoreHttpErrors(true) 
                      .execute();
        Log.d(TAG, "check_if_internet_available : " + response.statusCode());
        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e(TAG, "Jsoup_Exception: "+e);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply...i tried your code...its showing only 200 code when my ssid is in authentication state...for JsoupConnection.Response i am using Connection.Response....JsouConnection is not show for me... @Charfi

Comment: you can add a condition when the absent of the return so it's something different of 200

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change your method and use HttpURLConnection

```
URL url = new URL("http://microsenseindia.com");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();

int statusCode= connection.getResponseCode();
```

Comment: Yeah, i tried this way too...not working same problem happen again and again...

Comment: Can you try change RequestMethod("Post") ? can i see the return logs ?

Comment: D/Main2Activity: responseCode: 200
D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]:  hostname=microsenseindia.com;  servname=(null);  app_pid=28169;  app_uid=10568;  ai_flags=1024;  ai_family=0; ai_socktype=1 from prox result 0
D/Main2Activity: responseCode: 200

Comment: this is what my response while i requesting it in post method...

Comment: response code : 200 comes even if it is Authentication state...

Comment: Maybe you can try with 2 connection parts, the first one is the get auth state and the second the connect state (get and post)

Comment: Exactly, but i want to show the status like "Authentication" then "Connect" this two status may handle based on the response code if 302/Auth else 200/connect.this is what i want...but the problem is it wont show properly.

Comment: Will you tried it with your wifi ssid...? then you may get the problem if you have a hotspot network you can try...

Answer (score 0):

```
 try {
                while (true) {
                    sleep(1000);
                    final URL url;
                    try {
                        url = new URL("http://microsenseindia.com");
                        HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        huc.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                        huc.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        huc.connect();
                        huc.setReadTimeout(5000);
                        huc.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                        int responseCode = huc.getResponseCode();
                        Log.d(TAG, "responseCode: "+responseCode);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

this is what i am using as http connection methods.